# List, array and IEnumerable covariance

Tags: c#, arrays, list, ienumerable, covariance

I'll start with several postulates to better explain the context of my question:

### Array Covariance

#### Postulate 1.1

An array of a value type is not covariant. `int[]` cannot pass for `object[]`.

#### Postulate 1.2

An array of a reference type is covariant with a valid `IEnumerable`. `string[]` can pass for `IEnumerable<object>`).

#### Postulate 1.3

An array of a reference type is covariant with a valid covariant array. `string[]` can pass for `object[]`.

### List Covariance

#### Postulate 2.1 (same as 1.1)

A list of a value type is not covariant. `List<int>` cannot pass for `List<object>`.

#### Postulate 2.2 (same as 1.2)

A list of a reference type is covariant with a valid `IEnumerable`. `List<string>` can pass for `IEnumerable<object>`).

#### Postulate 2.3 (different from 1.3)

A list of a reference type is not covariant with a valid covariant `List`. `List<string>` cannot pass for `List<object>`).

---

My question concerns postulates 1.3, 2.2 and 2.3. Specifically:

1. Why can `string[]` pass for `object[]`, but `List<string>` not for `List<object>`?
2. Why can `List<string>` pass for `IEnumerable<object>` but not for `List<object>`?

Comment: Because a list is mutable and an array or `IEnumerable<T>` not. Only immutable collection classes should be covariant.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: While true, that argument applies to postulate 1.3 as well and as such doesn't explain why 1.3 is valid. ReSharper correctly warns in scenarios of 1.3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

List covariance is unsafe:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<object> objects = strings;
objects.Add(1);              //
```

Array covariance is also unsafe for the same reason:

```
string[] strings = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
object[] objects = strings;
objects[0] = 1;              //throws ArrayTypeMismatchException
```

array covariance in C# is recognised [as a mistake](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx), and has been present since version 1.

Since the collection cannot be modified through the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, it is safe to type a `List<string>` as an `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: Yes, it's most irksome that they allowed array covariance. They should not have.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Array covariance and contravariance could have been a good thing if the system included a types for "readable array reference" (covariant), "writable array reference" (contravariant), "item-swappable array reference" (type-independent), and "sortable array reference" (covariant combination of readable and item-swappable).  A general-purpose `Sort` routine could accept the latter type.  The lack of such specific types, however, does not eliminate the fact that a general-purpose sort routine needs a covariant sortable type.  Thus, `System.Array` was made covariant and sortable.

Comment: @supercat Well the language designers do say "this particular kind of covariance is broken" - did you look at the link Lee posted?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Writing an efficient general-purpose array-sort routine requires that the framework either support array covariance or generic types.  The designers of .NET had a choice between (1) having a framework where it was impossible to write an efficient general-purpose sort routine in user code, (2) not releasing a framework until generic support was complete, (3) including a variety of array-reference types, or (4) allowing array covariance as a kludge to make it possible for user code to write efficient general-purpose sorting routines.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I've read countless articles where the designer of something admits to a mistake.  As often as not, the "mistake" may have been at the time the best solution to a problem.  In some cases (as with Hoare's null pointers), the widespread belief that something was a "mistake" stems from a failure to recognize limitations in other proposed alternatives.

Comment: @supercat Or, in this case, it might be from reading a blog by one of the people who worked on the language design. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Mr. Lippert seems to suggest that it was a pragmatic decision, which was made in the interest of facilitating certain kinds of code. While other approaches might have been better, I'm not sure that they would have allowed .NET 1.0 to ship when it did, or whether .NET would have become successful if it had been delayed to allow one of the other approaches to be implemented properly. Further, the initial audience for .NET was Java programmers; as such, it borrowed a number of dubious concepts from Java. The biggest, which ties somewhat into the array issue...

Comment: ...is the assumption that for every heap instance type `Thing` there should be one storage location type for "promiscuous reference to `Thing`".  The .NET framework actually expands on that by adding a type `byref Thing`, but still makes no distinction between fields that encapsulate an object's identity, its mutable state, both, or neither, nor does it make any distinction between references which should be promiscuous and those which should be non-persistable, nor between those which should permit mutation and those which should not.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are covariant, but a `System.Int32[]` does not hold references to things which are derived from `System.Object`.  Within the .NET runtime, each value-type definition actually defines two kinds of things: a heap object type and a value (storage location) type.  The heap object type is derived from `System.Object`; the storage location type is implicitly convertible to the heap object type (which in turn derives from `System.Object`) but does not itself actually derive from `System.Object` nor anything else.  Although all arrays, including `System.Int32[]` are heap-object types, the individual *elements* of a `System.Int32[]` are instances of the storage location type.

The reason that a `String[]` can be passed to code expecting an `Object[]` is that the former contains "references to heap-object instances of type derived from type `String`", and the latter likewise for type `Object`.  Since `String` derives from `Object`, a reference to a heap-object of a type derived from `String` will also be a reference to a heap object which derives from `Object`, and a `String[]` will contain references to heap objects which derive from `Object`--exactly what code would expect to read from an `Object[]`.  By contrast, because an `int[]` [i.e. `System.Int32[]`] does not contain references to heap-object instances of type `Int32`, its contents will not conform to the expectations of code which is expecting `Object[]`.