# Why do casts between arrays of some value types seemingly break type safety?

Tags: c#, casting, clr

The following code:

```
object array = new int[] {-1};
Console.WriteLine("array is uint[]: {0}", array is uint[]);
Console.WriteLine("array[0]: {0:X}", ((uint[])array)[0]);
```

Prints the following, without any errors:

> array is uint[]: True
>   array[0]: FFFFFFFF

This seems peculiar to me, as it seems to break type safety. It is also a compile-time error to do the following:

```
int[] array = {-1};
uint[] test = (uint[])array;
```

Where does this inconsistency come from? Why is the CLR implemented like this?

Note that I don't believe this is the same thing as array covariance. In array covariance, the conversion is allowed because there is an implicit reference conversion; this is not the case here, where both types are value types and only have explicit casts between them.
For array covariance, the runtime also throws exceptions in some situations (when an assignment does not make sense). Exceptions are not thrown by the runtime in this case, even if assigning `test[0]` to a value outside the bounds of an `Int32`.

Comment: I'm guessing it is working in the first since all types are objects. So it can cast an object into a uint. 
In the second it is not allowing you because you probably shouldn't. But if you change it to (uint[])(object)array; It will allow you to as it is an object and does not recognize it as an int Type.

Comment: Because they are - note that it is compile time safety, not general .Net safe code. You can find a lot of interesting discussion on the topic by this search - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+array+covariant  and find answers like [List, array and IEnumerable covariance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061936/list-array-and-ienumerable-covariance).

Comment: Array covariance is a different topic; it doesn't allow you to change the type of the array and data stored in it. If you have a `Giraffe[] test`, then `((Animal[])test).GetType()` still returns a `Giraffe[]`, and that makes sense because a `Giraffe` is implicitly convertible to an `Animal`; an `UInt32` is not implicitly convertible to an `Int32`.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b942f9/how-to-convert-unsigned-integer-arrays-to-signed-arrays-and-vice-versa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in .NET are covariant in a rather broken way.

Arrays in C# are covariant in a **subset** of the ways that they are covariant in .NET. It's still broken, but it doesn't allow:

```
uint[] test = (uint[])new int[10]; // Compiler Error CS0030 C#
                                   // doesn't allow this covariance
```

But that's a C# rule; .NET allows it, it allows assignment between arrays where the types are integers (signed or unsigned) of the same size, or enums with the same size of underlying type.

And of course both .NET and C# both allow you to cast any array to `object`, and in both casting from object to any array type is legal but may fail at runtime. So `uint[] test = (uint[])(object)new int[10];` is allowed, because it's like the following steps:

```
object temp = new int[10];  // normal enough asignmnt.
uint[] test = (uint[])temp; // C# doesn't allow assigning
                            // int[] to uint[] but temp is
                            // object so the compiler
                            // doesn't know that's what
                            // you are doing, and .NET
                            // does allow it.
```

From a comment:

> Do you know why the CLR allows this conversion at all? Does it help with CLI compliance maybe (ie. allow languages without unsigned types to treat arrays as signed types)

Well consider that in CIL there is less difference when it comes to values on the stack between signed and unsigned values. If you use `clt` it will pop two values from the stack and compare them as signed values, whether they are signed or not, while `clt.un` will compare them as unsigned values, whether they are unsigned or not. Likewise

There's a freedom of moving between signed and unsigned types of the same size inherent to CIL.

Now, covariance means we can assign a value that is equivalent or narrower than what it is assigned to; that is it includes bivariance (assigning something narrower). C# doesn't consider `int` and `uint` bivariant; you have to explicitly cast between them, so it doesn't make sense to include them in the covariant assignment.

Comment: Do you know why the CLR allows this conversion at all? Does it help with CLI compliance maybe (ie. allow languages without unsigned types to treat arrays as signed types)?

Comment: I'll add a bit more on that.

Comment: @JonHanna Is it still covariance when int and uint types are not related via inheritance?

Comment: @Dzienny it's covariant if the type is equivalent or more specific; covariance includes bivariance (contravariance also includes bivariance). `int` and `uint` aren't equivalent in this sense in C#, but are in other ways in .NET.

Comment: @JonHanna Thank you, I just realized that they actually are related via inheritance, structs in C# inherit from Object.

Comment: @Dzienny yes, but they aren't **directly** related via inheritance. C# has assignable-to rules based on inheritance, but those aren't the only rules possible. C# relatedly has doesn't have types that are assignable-to each other (there's always a cast in at least one direction) and so even if it allowed value-type variance it couldn't have bivariance. The CLI though does have bivarance.

Comment: @JonHanna I see. So isn't that a different kind of covariance to the one discussed in the other question? The other question is focused on the covariance directly related to inheritance, but in case of `int` and `uint` the covariance (bivariance) is not directly related to inheritance, but some other rules.